# Selenium don't choose small span

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, firefox

We have this on our page and even thought everything else works, we can't select this and our best assumption is that this was made with the javaScript. Hopefully you can see that we are beginners.

[technical attributes 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofnz.jpg)

And we want to select the second span --

[technical attributes 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfHwb.jpg)

We are using this code to get even to this point.

```
package testProjekt2; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class testClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium-java-3.0.1\\geckodriver.exe");
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
           // this will create an object for the Firefox profile
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
           // this will Initialize the Firefox driver
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
         driver.get("https://tests.com:9000/tests");
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         //login here
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("cfadmin");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("20lipim18");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnlogin']")).click();
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         // Search for entities
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_txtAttr_1_22']")).click();
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_txtAttr_1_22']")).sendKeys("LTR*");
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_btnSearch']")).click();
         Thread.sleep(7000);
         //  chose one entity (first)
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i1_RSGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_1_ec20e4e5-4fd1-4963-becb-9087db26af74_CheckBox']")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*

[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i1_RSGrid1_ctl00__0']/td[1]/span[1]")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i1_RSGrid1_ctl00__1']/td[1]/span[1]")).click();
         Thread.sleep(5000);
      // Open Bulk Edit here
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i1_RSToolBar1']/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span/span/span")).click();
         Thread.sleep(5000);

         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='form1']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='form1']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
         Thread.sleep(7000);
         String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();  // save current window
         for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
            }  // switch to bulk edit window
         // Bulk Edit Window
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnEditTemplate']")).click();
         Thread.sleep(7000);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-accordion-accordion-header-1']")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jqg_techAttrGrid_5142']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jqg_techAttrGrid_5149']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnBulkEditNext']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57338_5142']")).click();
     String oldValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57338_5142']")).getText();
     //SAve value, here 2, change to 20
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57338_5142']")).sendKeys("20");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57338_5149']")).click();
     String oldValue2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57338_5149']")).getText();
     //SAve value, here 3, change to 30
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57338_5149']")).sendKeys("30");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57339_5142']")).click();
     String oldValue3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57339_5142']")).getText();
     //SAve value, here 2,5, change to 20,5
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CtrlTextRS_CTRL_57339_5142']")).sendKeys("20,5");        
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainGridButtonsContainer']/input[3]")).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);  //back to first
     //check value
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     // open Entity editor
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i1_RSGrid1_ctl00__0']/td[2]/a")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tblMain']/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]/img[3]")).click(); // show history
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnClose']")).click();  //close history
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li[3]/div/span[2]")).click();
         //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li[3]/div/span[2]")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li[3]/ul/li[3]/div/span[2]")).click();
         Thread.sleep(3000);
       //  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lnkOrgCatalog']")).click();
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cboOrg_DropDown']/div/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnSave']")).click();

    }
}
```

Any suggestion/recommendation is more then welcome, but an answer to our question is the focus in here. And the question is how could we select the second span from the group of technical attributes ? Or how could we click on small plus sign and to open up a small dropdown menu ?

EDITED:
HTML of the page:

```
                                    <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
                                        <li class="rtLI rtFirst"><div class="rtTop">
                                            <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="Entity Metadata" class="rtImg"><span title="Entity Metadata" class="rtIn">Entity Metadata</span>
                                        </div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
                                            <span class="rtSp"></span><span class="rtMinus"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="Common Attributes" class="rtImg"><span title="Common Attributes" class="rtIn">Common Attributes</span>
                                        </div><ul class="rtUL">
                                            <li class="rtLI"><div class="rtTop">
                                                <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="All" class="rtImg"><span title="All" class="rtIn">All</span>
                                            </div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid rtSelected">
                                                <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="daten" class="rtImg"><span title="daten" class="rtIn">daten</span>
                                            </div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
                                                <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="Daten" class="rtImg"><span title="Daten" class="rtIn">Daten</span>
                                            </div></li><li class="rtLI rtLast"><div class="rtBot">
                                                <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="OMS" class="rtImg"><span title="OMS" class="rtIn"> OMS</span>
                                            </div></li>
                                        </ul></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
                                            <span class="rtSp"></span><span class="rtPlus"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="Technical Attributes" class="rtImg"><span title="Technical Attributes" class="rtIn">Technical Attributes</span>
                                        </div><ul class="rtUL" style="display:none;">
                                            <li class="rtLI rtLast"><div class="rtBot">
                                                <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="All" class="rtImg"><span title="All" class="rtIn">All</span>
                                            </div></li>
                                        </ul></li><li class="rtLI rtLast"><div class="rtBot">
                                            <span class="rtSp"></span><span class="rtPlus"></span><img src="leaf.jpg" alt="Relationships" class="rtImg"><span title="Relationships" class="rtIn">Relationships</span>
                                        </div></li>
                                    </ul>
```

Comment: to select second span -> driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[@class=''rtMid]/span[2]")).click(); from technical attributes1. Hope this resolves the issue

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mail you. It's violation of non-compete. Sorry.

Comment: Please give the complete HTMLfor this page

Comment: Here it is. So I have lost around 15 minutes into editing this HTML, so I expect an answer from You Monica :-) Just kidding.